# How to run Sonar on a sub-module?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am using Sonar integration with Jenkins. I want to run Sonar only on a sub-module of a project and not the entire project. But, when I specify **-pl sub-module** in the options for Sonar, it says that it is not supported.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`cd` into the submodule and run `mvn sonar:sonar` there.

The drawback of this approach is that it will create a new top-level entry on the Sonar server; Sonar can't merge the results of a submodule run with an existing full analysis.